# Data Structures - Memory or Storage?

Tags: data-structures

When we talk about Data Structures (like array), do we refer to how the data is stored in RAM (contiguous memory locations) or the Hard Disk? If it also refers to the Hard Disk, how is the physical implementation different from RAM?

Answer (score 1):

We prefer the contiguous memory locations. The reason becomes obvious if we look at the hardware level.

**CPU** doesn't directly interact with the **RAM**, it does so via `CPU caches` (often divided into levels such as `L1`,`L2`,`L3` etc. with `L1` being smallest and fastest). Whenever **CPU** want some data, it sends request to `L1`, if not found, `L1` delegates the request to `L2` and so on (till hard disk) as shown in below figure:

[image]

Now when data is not found in any cache, we term it a **cache miss.** To reduce cache miss, when the **CPU** wants to access data at address `x` in **RAM**, it will not only fetch the data at address `x`, but also the neighborhood of address `x`(see below picture). Because we assume "if a particular memory location is referenced at a particular time, then it is likely that nearby memory locations will be referenced in the near future (aka **locality of reference**).

[image]

Accessing the array elements ensures sequential data access and thus **minimum cache misses**. You could now visualize why arrays are much faster than data structures like linked lists in terms of random/sequential data access. Same though process applies to other data structures as well.

Comment: Thanks @shanu but that is not what I asked

Comment: can you pls elaborate?

Comment: It's easier to imagine the data structures in a RAM because of the presence of memory cells in a tabular grid (like contiguous memory locations in case of an array). But a hard disk just contains files. How are various data structures implemented in a hard disk?